# Sql server convert/cast int to varchar independent of db language/collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, collation

I would like to convert/cast some int or bigint to varchar (in tsql).

But I would like it to be in English regardless of database language, collation, etc.  (I need to parse it back on the client side)

Basically I am looking for tsql equivalent of this C# code 1234.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

What should I do? Is this language independent? convert(varchar, 1234)

Comment: a number will always be use 'english' digits (they're actually hindu-arabic numerals!); do you mean US english number formatting?

Comment: Yes, basically I am looking for tsql equivalent of this C# code 1234.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 so that I can parse it back later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `CONVERT(varchar, some_int)` is culture invariant.

The same is not true for money or datetime

Comment: I think so too. but documentation doesn't say anything about it. I thought better to ask.

Comment: @john I was trying to find better information on it and set up a test/demo for you at http://odata.stackexchange.com - but I think SET LANGUAGE only affects so many things even with money converts.

Answer (score 2):

For int, a basic CAST or CONVERT won't add separators

For casting back, this is OK `1234567` but these assorted culture ones aren't: `1,234,567` or `1'234'567` or `1.234.567`. And you can't generate the latter in T-SQL *cleanly* anyway